# Make HTTP Server in Python File Inherit the Same Arguments as the Command Line Version

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I want start an HTTP server server in a Python file that inherits the arguments as the command line tool.

Which are:

```
python3 -m http.server --help               
usage: server.py [-h] [--cgi] [--bind ADDRESS] [--directory DIRECTORY] 
[port]

positional arguments:
  port                  Specify alternate port [default: 8000]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --cgi                 Run as CGI Server
  --bind ADDRESS, -b ADDRESS
                        Specify alternate bind address [default: all
                        interfaces]
--directory DIRECTORY, -d DIRECTORY
                    Specify alternative directory [default:current
                    directory]
```

I figure this would be useful because I need three of these arguments (the `bind`, `port` and  `directory`) in my own program and so instead of rewriting the code I could just inherit those. The only one of these for which I have no use for is the `cgi` option, to which perhaps I could remove that?

I also want the message: `Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...` to be printed.

But besides that I want to define my own implementation for handing GETs, POSTs, etc.

Here is an example of what I have so far trying to replicate those arguments and that print message in my own HTTP server:

```
from http.server import ThreadingHTTPServer, HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    # ... custom HTTP GET and POST implementations ...

def start(server_class=ThreadingHTTPServer, handler_class=Handler, bind='0.0.0.0', port=8000):
    server_address = (bind, port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print('Serving HTTP on ' + bind + ' port ' + port + ' (http://' + bind + ':' + port + '/) ...')
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) == 2:
        start(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        start()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `http.server` argument handling is [defined inline in its `__main__` handling](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/http/server.py#L1243).  There’s no way to inherit it short of extreme patching (perhaps via `argparse`).

Comment: Looking at the code, it would seem that the `__main__` only block is not even in a handler class which I think means I would have to patch over the entire file. Furthermore, the fact that it's in a `__main__` only block tells me that this definitely is not meant to be inherited anyways. Looks like I should take a peek at the source code more often! Anyways, I should be good just copying out what I want from that `__main__` only block. Thank you again!